# Combine an array and a linkedList

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a String array and LinkedList of strings and I want to combine/map them.
The string list looks like this:

```
String[] data = new String[5];
Output:
[cern, https://home.cern/, zenodo, https://zenodo.org/]
[openaire, https://www.openaire.eu/, zenodo, https://zenodo.org/]
```

The linkedList has two values: "Zenodo" & "Covid19". What I want to do is to combine those two and get the result as shown down below:

```
[cern, https://home.cern/, zenodo, https://zenodo.org/,Zenodo]
[openaire, https://www.openaire.eu/, zenodo, https://zenodo.org/, Zenodo]
[cern, https://home.cern/, zenodo, https://zenodo.org/,Covid19]
[openaire, https://www.openaire.eu/, zenodo, https://zenodo.org/, Covid19]
```

Is there any way I can accomplish that?

Comment: You want to *append* a string from the list to the end of the `data` array? Or you want to set `data[4]` to a string from the list? What have you tried? What is the problem with your attempt?

Comment: There is certainly at least "a" way to accomplish that. More important is the question: what have you tried yourself? We can't consicely answer this as it stands, as there are too many open possibilities, and any answer would have a lot of details to guess.

Comment: Hello sorry for not explaining that well. @Someprogrammerdude I want to accomplish the first thing you said. I have tried a lot of ways to do it, mostly with for loops but it seems that it doesn't work...

Comment: Considering that you create an array of five elements, and populate only four of them, I would actually have expected the second thing: To just assign a string to `data[4]`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok if that is the most efficient way I don't mind..

Comment: @CostasGinos Have you considered writing a class rather than keeping a string array with elements which seem to be related properties?

Comment: @MCEmperor mmmh, do you have any reference so I can understand the way to achieve that?